# ExecuteReader not returning anything

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, varchar

I have a table called 'MatchType' and it contains:

```
ID | MatchTypeName
1  | One Day
2  | Two Day
3  | T20
```

I have a method to retrieve a record from that table based on a sting that will match a value in `MatchTypeName`:

```
public static int GetByName(string matchType)
{          
    MatchType item = new MatchType();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(BaseDataAccessLayer.GetConnectionStringByName()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(STORED_PROC_GetByName, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@matchTypeName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = matchType;
            con.Open();

            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                item.LoadFromReader(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    return item.Id;
}
```

This method calls this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MatchType_GetByName]
    (@matchTypeName varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [Id], [MatchTypeName]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[MatchType]
    WHERE 
        [MatchTypeName] = @matchTypeName

    RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

When calling the `GetByName` method I am passing in a string "One Day". I have confirmed this through debugging. I can't post an error message that is helpful as there isn't one being generated. Just no data is being returned in the reader...

I have a couple of other methods and stored procedures that use a similar process and they work.  The only thing that I can see is the difference is that I am using the `WHERE` clause on a varchar/string value which is something that the other queries don't do...

Yet i can run this stored proc and it returns all the records..

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        [Id],
        [MatchTypeName]
    FROM
        [dbo].[MatchType]
    RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

Comment: Have you tried running the stored proc in SQL to see what the results are?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Yes i have tried that and it does select the correct record when entering a value into the Execute dialog.. :)

Comment: Can the MatchTypeName have extra white space or something like that? Try trimming or use 'like' to see if that's the case

Comment: You can also test to see if your LoadFromReader() is working properly by adding a default value to the SP, such as "One Day," as part of debugging.

Comment: Even if i plug in a hard coded value into the WHERE clause in the stored proc, i am still getting nothing in the response..

Answer (score 7):

The default length for `varchar` declared without size is 1. You declared it like that in your stored proc parameter so you're only passing the first character.

Change your declaration:

```
(@matchTypeName varchar)
```

to a relevant size:

```
(@matchTypeName varchar(20))
```

Also, add the size in the code and make sure that the case in your parameter name matches your stored proc:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@matchTypeName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = matchType;
```

Comment: Apologies, i did have the size of the  varchar declared in the original code.  I obviously forgot to reinstate the code after making changes to try and get this working.  I have put this code back in and unfortunately this hasn't changed the outcome..

Comment: So what's the outcome now? Does the edited code in question work or not? If not, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: After running the stored procedure and then attempting to read from the IDataReader, the reader is null...As in nothing has been returned from the database...  Yet executing the stored procedure in sql with an appropriate parameter returns a correct record..

Comment: One more thing - the case of param names should match.

Comment: I have tidied that one up.  Again it was one of those thing i hadn't corrected after hours of trying to get this going...

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is running the query and showing the results (which is why it works in SSMS), but doesn't actually return anything.  Try this (note, I haven't actually tested it).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MatchType_GetByName]
    @matchTypeName varchar(20),
    @matchTypeID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        @matchTypeID = [Id], [MatchTypeName]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[MatchType]
    WHERE 
        [MatchTypeName] = @matchTypeName

    RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(STORED_PROC_GetByName, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matchTypeName", matchType);
            con.Open();

            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                item.LoadFromReader(reader);
            }
        }
```

[SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks..  Have tried that way using 'AddWithValue"  Unfortunately is doesn't change anything.  There is obviously something wrong with the stored procedure returning a result...